# GSON MalformedJsonException with utf8 double quote

Tags: java, utf-8, gson, jira

On frontend I use

```
JSON.stringfy({comment: "1. It's better to use standard abbreviation for Minutes and Seconds, the “ “Mn” “Sc” is hard to understand"})
```

On backend:

```
Comment comment = new Gson().fromJson(value, Comment.class);
```

Get:

```
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 213 path $.comment
```

Problem with symbols:

[image]

With other string it`s works

Comment: try to add a backslash before -> " \" "

Comment: Either you need to escape double cote in your comment string using \ (i.e \"Mn\") or use single quote (i.e 'Mn')

Comment: is a http://graphemica.com/%E2%80%9C not `"`